# unable to implement onChildClick() in extendable ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

`setOnGroupExpandListener()` is working fine, but child node does not invoke. What could be the issue?

Activity class :

```
public class MainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ExpandableListView expandbleLis = getExpandableListView();
        expandbleLis.setDividerHeight(2);
        expandbleLis.setGroupIndicator(null);
        //expandbleLis.setClickable(true);

        setGroupData();
        setChildGroupData();

        NewAdapter mNewAdapter = new NewAdapter(groupItem, childItem);
        mNewAdapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE),this);
        getExpandableListView().setAdapter(mNewAdapter);


        expandbleLis.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener()
          {
           public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) 
           {
            Log.e("onGroupExpand", "OK");
           }
          });

        expandbleLis.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener()
          {
           public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) 
           {
            Log.e("onGroupCollapse", "OK");
           }
          });

        expandbleLis.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener()
          {
           @Override
           public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
             int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Log.e("OnChildClickListener", "OK");
            return false;
           }
          });
    }

    public void setGroupData() {
        groupItem.add("TechNology");
        groupItem.add("Mobile");
        groupItem.add("Manufacturer");
        groupItem.add("Extras");
    }

    ArrayList<String> groupItem = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Object> childItem = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public void setChildGroupData() {
        /**
         * Add Data For TecthNology
         */
        ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Java");
        child.add("Drupal");
        child.add(".Net Framework");
        child.add("PHP");
        childItem.add(child);

        /**
         * Add Data For Mobile
         */
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Android");
        child.add("Window Mobile");
        child.add("iPHone");
        child.add("Blackberry");
        childItem.add(child);
        /**
         * Add Data For Manufacture
         */
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("HTC");
        child.add("Apple");
        child.add("Samsung");
        child.add("Nokia");
        childItem.add(child);
        /**
         * Add Data For Extras
         */
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Contact Us");
        child.add("About Us");
        child.add("Location");
        child.add("Root Cause");
        childItem.add(child);
    }


        }
```

Adapter:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class NewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    public ArrayList<String> groupItem, tempChild;
    public ArrayList<Object> Childtem = new ArrayList<Object>();
    public LayoutInflater minflater;
    public Activity activity;

    public NewAdapter(ArrayList<String> grList, ArrayList<Object> childItem) {
        groupItem = grList;
        this.Childtem = childItem;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act) {
        this.minflater = mInflater;
        activity = act;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        tempChild = (ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition);
        TextView text = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
        }
        text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText(tempChild.get(childPosition));
        /*convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, tempChild.get(childPosition),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });*/
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groupItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.grouprow, null);
        }
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(groupItem.get(groupPosition));
        //((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please return true from this method in your adapter.

```
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

and also whats the point of using `ExpandableListActivity` if you are setting listeners like `onChildClickListebner` manually. Just override `onChildClick()` method in `ExpandableListActivity`. You can also override methods like `onGroupExpand()` and `onGroupCollapse()` present in `ExpandableListActivity`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html